# Pass object to SASlideMenuViewController subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, saslidemenu

After login succeeds my `LoginViewController` will `loginSegue` to the `SASlideMenuRootViewController`, which then in its own `viewDidLoad` automatically looks for a `leftMenu` segue (that I have set up to my `MenuViewController`) and sets this up as its leftMenu property.

This all works great but I can't see how I am supposed to pass dependencies from the `LoginViewController` to my `MenuViewController`.

Have tried the following as is the usual way to do this but it fails as obviously the `leftMenu` property hasn't yet been configured as `viewDidLoad` doesn't run until after this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"])
    {
        // This works
        SASlideMenuRootViewController *slideViewController = (SASlideMenuRootViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        // menuViewController is nil :(
        MenuViewController *menuViewController = (MenuViewController *)slideViewController.leftMenu;

        // I want to pass this along
        menuViewController.account = self.account;
    }
}
```

Do I need to subclass `SASlideMenuRootViewController` just to pass this value along? Seems messy.

https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to subclass `SASlideMenuRootViewController` just to pass this along.